# PopupNotifier is not working in timer class

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

`PopupNotifier` is not working, when it is placed inside the `timer class`, if we put the `PopupNotifier` out side the timer class it is working fine for me, the following code as using for this.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bool needToShowInTaskbar = this.ShowInTaskbar;
            WindowState initialWindowState = this.WindowState;
             // making window invisible
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
             // showing and hiding window
            this.Show();
            this.Hide();
             // restoring original settings
            this.ShowInTaskbar = needToShowInTaskbar;
            this.WindowState = initialWindowState;
            SetTimer();
     }

     private  void SetTimer()
            {
                m_mainTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                m_mainTimer.Interval = 60000;   // every one min
                m_mainTimer.Elapsed += m_mainTimer_Elapsed;
                m_mainTimer.AutoReset = false;  // makes it fire only once
                m_mainTimer.Start(); // Start
                m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
            }

        private void m_mainTimer_Elapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
               try
                {
                    LoadData();
                    PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
                    popup.TitleText = joomla.subject;
                    popup.ContentText = joomla.body;
                    popup.Popup();
                    m_timerTaskSuccess = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    m_timerTaskSuccess = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (m_timerTaskSuccess)
                    {
                        m_mainTimer.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: _"is not working"_ is not enough to describe a problem. Are you expecting from us that we run your code to see an exception or other issue?

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` makes callbacks from a threadpool thread, not the main UI thread. You might need to use `BeginInvoke()` to call a method that does the `LoadData()` and the rest of the code that's currently inside a try/catch. Or you could just try using a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, am ask this question why it not working , means there is any issue in the method calling or not,  for me while debugging it not showing any exception or any other issues.

Comment: @ Matthew Watson thanks for the solution it works for me , i have placed the solution as answer

Comment: How about removing the exception-eating catch clause to see the actual error that occurs?

Comment: @UweKeim it is same the program will debug with out any error. , now i got the exact solution , thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While changing the timer to `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` it work well for me.

```
 private  void SetTimer()
        {
            dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);

            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

        }
```